# Minecraft 1.12 Multiplayer world to singleplayer

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have a multiplayer server world that I run locally on my computer. I would like to copy that world into a single player save. Easy explanation.

Problem comes when I try copy and pasting the world; it gets the correct world but has not saved my player, specifically. I spawn in the world's original spawn, which is way too far from my server's spawn to reach, and I have no items. Is there a way to fix this loss of player data? I'm the only player that has logged into the multiplayer server so I'm the only player data present

**Update:**

The playerdata .dat file is there and it has my uuid in the name, with dashes. I have tried copying my world over directly, and I've also tried creating a world, entering the world once, and then replacing the folder contents with my world files. Both have the same result.

Comment: Are you using a vanilla server or a modified server?

Comment: @IronAnvil Vanilla server. No mods or even plugins installed. It's a craftbukkit vanilla

Comment: craftbukkit is not vanilla and is quite different from vanilla. [This is the only server that is vanilla](https://minecraft.net/en-us/download/server).  I recommend adding that information to the question.  Using craftbukkit requires more steps to properly migrate the world to single player.  [Here is an answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/321300/186522) that explains what happens when craftbukkit is run the first time with a vanilla world.  It doesn't answer your question but explains some of the complication.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transfer world from multiplayer to singleplayer and continue with the right progress](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/242077/transfer-world-from-multiplayer-to-singleplayer-and-continue-with-the-right-prog)

Answer (score 1):

Provided you're copying the world folder, your player position should be in the same location. Go into the file once you've pasted it and check in the following directory:

`C:\...\.minecraft\saves\<world name>\playerdata`

In there should be a .DAT file with your UUID on it (you can find your UUID on [this website](https://namemc.com/)). If there is not a .DAT file with your UUID on it then it means that either for whatever reason you don't have a .DAT file for that world, or your server has stored it somewhere else. Try looking elsewhere in your server files for a .DAT file with your UUID (or possibly even IGN) on it.

Moving the .DAT file into the file path for your world mentioned above should update your inventory, location and such.

Comment: The .dat file is there and it has my uuid in the name, with dashes. I have tried copying my world over directly, and I've also tried creating a world, entering it once, and then replacing the folder contents with my world.

Answer (score 0):

From the [wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Player.dat_format):

> .dat files are used by servers to store the state of individual players. The format is also used within level.dat files to store the state of the singleplayer player, which overrides any .dat files with the same name as the singleplayer player.

I think this explains your problem of disappearing inventories when moving from multiplayer to singlepayer : level.dat override your existing player datas

Maybe you could try without the level.dat file and let it re-generate it, so that it won't override your player.dat ?

Genuinely interested to see if the game could use a map without the original level.dat, please post update.

Here is my update after trying my hint:

- I moved a whole multiplayer map from my server folder into the saves
  folder in the minecraft game folder.
- I then deleted the level.dat inside the map folder.
- I started minecraft and went to singleplayer. I did not see the map in it.
- I then created a map , named exactly the same as the map moved.

The game loaded pretty quickly and it worked.
I kept the gamemode, my inventory, my position in the map ...
And of course the map was unchanged (data folder is intact)

Comment: I'll try this out and let you know.